# Homogenization of principal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to prove that if $I=\langle f\rangle\subseteq k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a principal ideal, then $I^h$ (the homogenization of $I$) is generated by the homogenization of $f$, $f^h=x_0^df(x_1/x_0,\ldots,x_n/x_0)$, where $d$ is the degree of $f$. I have $I^h$ defined as the ideal generated by the set $\{g^h:g\in I\}$. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition we have $I^h=\langle i^h\vert i\in I\rangle$. If $I=\langle f\rangle$ then $I=\{rf\vert r\in R\}$ for $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ so $\{i^h\vert i\in I\}$ is given by $\{(rf)^h\vert r\in R\}$. If you inspect these homogenizations and then show that $\{(rf)^h\vert r\in R\}$ is already an ideal, then $I^h:=\langle \{(rf)^h\vert r\in R\}\rangle=\{(rf)^h\vert r\in R\}$ and you are done. (Notice how the homogenizations distibutes over products! Do we have $(a\cdot b)^h=a^h\cdot b^h$?)

Comment: The thing I'm having trouble with is precisely proving $\{(rf)^h\mid r\in R\}$ is an ideal, since $r^h+s^h\neq (r+s)^h$

Comment: Yes you are right and in particular after some calculation I found that indeed $I^h$ is only _generated_ by the set I described. Since for $I=\langle x\rangle$ we have $xy^{n-1}+x^n=(x+x^n)^h=(1+x^{n-1})x)^h\in I^h$ for $n\ge 1$ but the some of such two homogenizations is not in the set I prescribed so this _can't_ be the whole ideal! Clearly $\langle f^h\rangle \in I^h$. For the other inclusion: $I^h:=\langle r^hf^h\vert r\in R\rangle =\langle\sum \alpha r^hf^h\vert r\in R, \alpha\in R[y]\rangle\subseteq \langle \sum \alpha'f^h\vert \alpha'\in R[y]\rangle\subseteq \langle f^h\rangle$.

Comment: I hope this helps and is enough. Unfortunately I'll be out of the house shortly, so I can't answer until probably tomorrow. But feel free to ask further questions!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly $(f^h)\subset I^h$. Let $g^h\in I^h$, then $g=g^h(1,x_1,\dots,x_n)\in I$ and hence $g=pf$ for some $p\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Now

$$
\begin{align*}
g^h &= x_0^{\text{deg}(g)}p(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0)f(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0)\\
    &= x_0^{\text{deg}(f)}x_0^{\text{deg}(p)} p(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0)f(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0) \\
 &= p^hf^h
\end{align*}
$$
so we also have $I^h\subset (f^h)$.

Comment: But an element of $I^h$ is of the form $(r_1f)^h+\ldots (r_kf)^h$

Comment: An element of $I^h$ is $g^h$ for some $g\in I$. In particular it satisfies $g^h(1,x_1,\dots,x_n)\in I$.

Comment: $I^h$ is not just those type of elements; it is the ideal generated by them.

Comment: True. Bad choice of words. What I meant was, elements $g^h$ generate $I^h$, so it suffices to see that they are contained in $(f^h)$ to conclude that $I^h\subset (f^h)$.